# How to define variable number of "and" gates (logic gates) programatically?

Tags: verilog

I need to create 31 "and" gates, and I tried using a `for` loop and `begin`:

```
for(i=1;i<=30;i=i+1)
    begin
    and g[i](u[i],p[i],q[1]);  // Line 29
    end
end
```

But, it is showing syntax error at "and"- line 29.
Is there any way it can be declared and initialised programmatically rather than declaring each "and" gate?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two other ways. You can use an array of instances

```
and g[31:1](u,p, q);
```

or you can use a generate loop

```
genvar i;
for(i=1;i<=31;i=i+1) begin : block
  and g(u[i],p[i],q[i]);
end
```

This creates the `and` gates block[1].g through block[31].g